# Data values in the parameters are beeing copied to the other parameters c++, c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c#-4.0

In c++ the method that I am exporting is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __thiscall A::check(char *x,char *y,char *z)
{
  temp=new B(x,y,z);
}
```

In c# I am importing this method like this:

```
[DllImport("IDLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.ThisCall, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "check")]
    public static extern int check(string x, string y, string z);
```

I am calling this method in c# like this and passing the values:

```
public int temp()
{
  string x="sdf";
  string y="dfggh";
  string z="vbnfg";
  int t;

  t=Class1.check(x,y,z);
  return t;
}
```

The problem is that when I debug in to the native code I see that the parameters x,y,z having values sdf,dfggh,vbnfg and being altered when they reach c++ dll like this even before it is entering the native c++ dll method.

```
x=dfggh,y=vbnfg,z=null value
```

and is giving me the error saying that null pointer value is passed to the function. Can any one help me out fixing this weird problem.

Comment: Just had a look at some code I wrote a few years ago. Try adding `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` before each of the `string` arguments. The `UnmanagedType.LPStr` means _A pointer to a null-terminated array of ANSI characters_.

Comment: Is that true that only z becomes null, and there is no problem with x and y? If yes, then check those parts of the ctor of B which modifies z.

Comment: @kol --- even before entering the entering the constructor B itself the values are being changed.

Comment: @hmjd --- i tried what you mentioned but having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your native method is an instance(vs static) method. I guess your first parameter gets mapped to 'this' somehow.

Here is an example:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
__declspec(dllexport) static int __stdcall check(char *x,char *y,char *z)
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
    f<<x<<endl;
    f<<y<<endl;
    f<<z<<endl;
    return 0;

    }

__declspec(dllexport) int __thiscall checkInst(char *x,char *y,char *z)
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("c:\\temp\\testInst.txt");
    f<<x<<endl;
    f<<y<<endl;
    f<<z<<endl;
    return 0;

    }
};
```

see the **static** keyword on the first one?

Imports(i used the mangled names because I'm lazy):

```
[DllImport("TestDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "?check@A@@SGHPAD00@Z")]
    public static extern int check(string x, string y, string z);

    [DllImport("TestDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "?checkInst@A@@QAEHPAD00@Z")]
    public static extern int checkInst(IntPtr theObject, string x, string y, string z);
```

That makes it work just like that:

```
check("x", "yy", "zzz");
```

the instance method requires an IntPtr

```
IntPtr obj = IntPtr.Zero;
checkInst(obj, "1", "12", "123");
```

and the contents of my test.txt are:

```
x
yy
zzz
```

and testInst.txt

```
1
12
123
```

Comment: what do you mean by "native method is an instance(vs static) method"

Comment: A::check looks like a non static(which requires an object) method on a class A, you need to export static method or a function for P/Invoke to work

Comment: i think there is no need for a method needs to be static to use pinvoke. So as the method is of type __stdcall it needs to be static?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2354222/842543 You cannot just call statically a method from C# - it requires an object on the other side? who will construct it?

Comment: ok i am getting confused here can you provide a sample code that says your point. Basic example will be good enough.

Comment: that worked thank you but came across another error as an extension of this can you please take a look at this as well at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855149/getting-an-access-violation-error-is-c-sharp-while-calling-the-c-code"